# Tab Navigator Doesn't work when importing files

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to create a bottom tab navigator and am importing 3 classes. But it doesn't work. The app doesn't throw any errors, but fails to open. It works fine if all classes are in the same file. But I really need to import as the classes are massive. Each individual class is working perfectly.

My code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {createBottomTabNavigator,createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
import FriendScreen from './screens/FriendScreen'
import InstructionsScreen from './screens/InstructionsScreen'
import ItemsScreen from './screens/ItemsScreen'
const TabNavigator=createBottomTabNavigator({Game:FriendScreen,Instructions:InstructionsScreen,Items:ItemsScreen},{initialRouteName:"Game"})
export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator)
```

I've read a number of code segments on the internet, but can't locate the error

Comment: Can you share code that you had already tried

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you didn't follow the normal structure defined by `react-navigation`.

When defining a screen it should be like:

```
RouteName:{
    screen:Component.
}
```

You TabNavigator should be:

```
const TabNavigator=createBottomTabNavigator({
    Game: { 
        screen : FriendScreen 
    },
    Instructions: { 
        screen : InstructionsScreen
    },
    Items:{ 
        screen : ItemsScreen
    }
},
{
    initialRouteName:"Game"
})
```

Comment: Ok, this code doesn't work either... Same issue (cutting import part, unchanged and was making it too long):

const TabNavigator=createBottomTabNavigator({Game:{screen:FriendScreen},Instructions:{screen:InstructionsScreen},Items:{screen:ItemsScreen}},{initialRouteName:"Game"})
export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator)

the other files:
https://pastebin.com/MS8WfHcm

https://pastebin.com/WfWPdvgx

https://pastebin.com/TUttZBhy